# Sort Table so that only the first x rows are images, after that Sort Table by Date

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I've tried looking for this, but couldn't find an example or don't know if this is possible.

I have a table for a Newsfeed like features with a combination of images and text only posts.

I want to sort the table so that the first 10 instances are images, and after that the table would be sorted by date.

Right now, I have duplicates in the Newsfeed because I'm essentially running the query twice, once to sort the last 10 images to the top, and then another sorted by date.

```
SELECT a.images, a.text, a.created_date
FROM newsfeed a
ORDER BY a.images, a.create_date 
LIMIT 10

SELECT a.images, a.text, a.created_date
from newsfeed a
ORDER BY a.created_date
```

Is there a way to combine these two queries so that the first 10 are images, and the rest is sorted by date?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: could you just add a `UNION` between the 2 queries?

Answer (score 0):

If I assume that you mean that the images are not `NULL`, then include that as an `order by` key:

```
SELECT n.images, n.text, n.created_date
FROM newsfeed n
ORDER BY (n.images is not null) desc, n.create_date ;
```

The `is not null` returns a boolean, with `1` for true and `0` for false. The `desc` puts the non-NULL values first.

Note that I also changed the table alias from the meaningless `a` to an abbreviation for the table name.